# Apache buffer overflow with too many virtual host

Tags: php, apache, centos, buffer-overflow, file-descriptor

I have Centos 7 with httpd 2.4.6-45.el7.centos.4 and PHP 5.6.31

I'm having a buffer overflow detected when I'm trying to load a website as soon as I go over 1000+ Virtual Hosts. Each virtual host have an error_log.
But I can load a simple phpinfo(), or html page.

The only tweak I made was to be able to start httpd without busting the no file limit. (I was getting too many open file error)

```
/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d/limits.conf
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=30000
```

When I count the number of FD here /proc/16402/fd, I have 1051.
But sadly no 1024 limits when I check :

```
cat /proc/16402/limits
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max processes             256005               256005               processes
Max open files            30000                30000                files
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       256005               256005               signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, it's an issue with mod_php. I configure php-fpm and it's working now.